Run WITH FUNCTION [Function Name] SELECT in SQLPlus or SQLcl
I developed this query in SQL Developer:
WITH FUNCTION AMS_SUBTRACT_WORKDAY(VDATE IN DATE, VDAYS IN NUMBER)
    RETURN DATE
    IS
    VENDD DATE;
    VDYWR NUMBER := 5;
    VDYCL NUMBER := 7;
    VDAYD NUMBER;
    VDAY2 NUMBER := VDAYS;
    VWEKS NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT TO_NUMBER(VDATE - TRUNC(VDATE, 'IW')) INTO VDAYD FROM DUAL;
        IF VDAYD > VDAY2 THEN 
            VENDD := VDATE - VDAY2;
        ELSE 
            VDAY2 := VDAY2 - VDAYD;
            VENDD := TRUNC(VDATE, 'IW');
            VENDD := VENDD - (TRUNC(VDAY2 / 5) * 7) - 2;
            VDAY2 := VDAY2 - (TRUNC(VDAY2 / 5) * 5);
            VENDD := VENDD - VDAY2;
        END IF;
        RETURN VENDD;
    END AMS_SUBTRACT_WORKDAY;
    SELECT AMS_SUBTRACT_WORKDAY(DATE '2024-09-28', 5) RES FROM DUAL;

Which gives the following result:

The problem is that if I run it via SQLPlus or SQLcl, it seems the WITH clause it is not being recognized as part of the SELECT. & thus it stops processing.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Your code runs fiddle - although I did need to use / as the query terminator in the fiddle rather than ; (however, I'm not sure the function is correct if you compare it to my answer to your previous question).

In SQL*Plus and SQLcl, PL/SQL code must be terminated by a forward slash to run*. For example:
SQL> with function test1 return number is begin return 1; end;
  2  select test1 from dual;
  3  /

     TEST1
----------
         1

SQL>

* This simplistic summary is not really true in recent versions of Oracle, because SQL and PL/SQL are gradually merging. The above code is most accurately still called a SQL statement, although it clearly uses PL/SQL inside it. Statement parsing can get weird where the two languages meet, like in object types and triggers.
In general, if SQL*Plus reads the first few tokens(?) and determines that the code will include semicolons that do not end a statement, it will look for a forward slash on a line by itself. Other IDEs will work differently, and some will not correctly parse PL/SQL WITH functions correctly at all. When it comes to actually executing the statement, for example if you ran it dynamically within an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE string, the forward slash should NOT be included. (Similar to the way a dynamically executed SQL statement should not have a terminating semicolon.)
